# code and classes are not secure using proguard

Tags: android, proguard, secure-coding

I want to secure my code from reverse engineering And I have already used Proguard and defined rules too, But after reverse engineering I am getting all my classes with same name and also code in it. I want to secure whole code also. I don't understand what I am doing wrong

```
  release {
            minifyEnabled true
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"true"]
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Rules

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao {
public static java.lang.String TABLENAME;
}
-ignorewarnings
 -keep class * {
     public private *;
 }
-keep class  org.greenrobot.greendao.internal.**{*;}
-dontwarn org.greenrobot.greendao.database.**
-keep class org.greenrobot.greendao.**
# If you do not use Rx:
-dontwarn rx.**
-keep class **$Properties
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao {
public static java.lang.String TABLENAME;
}
-keep class **$Properties
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }
-keep class com.xxxxxx.beanclasses.* { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
-dontwarn io.card.**
-ignorewarnings
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.**


-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-dontwarn com.android.databinding.library.**
-dontwarn android.app.job.JobParameters.**
-dontwarn cdflynn.android.library.crossview.**
-dontwarn com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.**
-dontwarn com.amitshekhar.**
-dontwarn com.amitshekhar.**
-dontwarn com.example.crystalrangeseekbar.**
-dontwarn com.dd.processbutton.**
-dontwarn com.daimajia.numberprogressbar.**
-dontwarn com.dd.processbutton.**
-dontwarn com.dd.processbutton.**
-dontwarn com.github.clans.fab.**
-dontwarn com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.**
-dontwarn com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.**
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.messaging.**
-dontwarn com.google.maps.android.**
-dontwarn com.gun0912.tedpermission.**
-dontwarn com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.**
-dontwarn com.xxxx.obeebottomnav.**
-dontwarn com.shehabic.droppy.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn com.vlonjatg.progressactivity.**
-dontwarn com.wang.avi.**
-dontwarn com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.**
-dontwarn com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.**
-dontwarn com.yarolegovich.lovelydialog.**
-dontwarn de.codecrafters.tableview.**
-dontwarn es.dmoral.toasty.**
-dontwarn io.apptik.widget.mslider.**
-dontwarn ir.mirrajabi.searchdialog.**
-dontwarn me.didik.component.**
-dontwarn me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.**
-dontwarn net.cachapa.expandablelayout.**
-dontwarn mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.Conscrypt.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean.**
-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**

-dontwarn com.google.common.util.concurrent.CheckedFuture.**
-dontwarn android.app.job.JobParameters.**
-dontwarn com.vstechlab.testeasyfont.easyfonts.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.Conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.Conscrypt.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout.**
-dontwarn org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout.**

-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }



-dontwarn com.google.common.util.**
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.**
-dontwarn androidx.work.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
#retrofit
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclassmembers class **.R$layout {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Where I am wrong can any one please check rules, already I have search on stackoverflow for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove:

```
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

I believe this is the root cause.

I recommend using `@Keep` annotation instead proguard rules for every class from your code that you want to keep - read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71712112/11958566) for my reasons for not preferring proguard rules